# Navigation Menu To Overlap Frames

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, frame

I am going through the process of revamping a very old website that used frames. I have started with the navigation menu, adopting the functionality of a jQuery drop down.

Although the menu successfully drops down on the homepage, when i have i navigate to another, the drop down menu's fail to overlap into the new frame. I can see a part of the drop down, however it is going 'behind' the new frame.

**FrameStructure.html:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb">

<title>Product Menu</title>

</head>
<frameset rows="170px,*" border="0">

<frame id="PageHeader" name="PageHeader" src="PageHeader.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" title="Page Header" noresize>

<frameset id="PageFrames" name="PageFrames" cols="250px,*">
    <frame id="PageNavigation" name="PageNavigation" src="Nav.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" title="Page Navigation" noresize>
        <frameset id="ContentFrames" name="ContentFrames" rows="*,0">
        <frame id="PageContent" name="PageContent" src="Blank.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" title="Input Page" noresize>
        <frame id="PageHelp" name="PageHelp" style="BORDER-TOP: white 2px solid;" src="Help.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" title="Help Page">
    </frameset>     
</frameset>

<noframes>Your browser does not support frames</noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

**PageHeader.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">


<script src="javascript/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>


<title>Page Header</title>

<link type="text/css" href="css/redesign-main.css" rel="stylesheet">  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>

<!-- JavaScript Functionality to create drop down menu -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {       
        $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
        $('nav li').hover(
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(300);
            },
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(300);
        }
        );       
    });
</script>



<style>
/*nav {background:#FFF;float:left;}*/
nav ul {
    text-align:left;    
}
nav ul li {
    float:left; 
    display:inline;
    border-right: 1px solid #083D72;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background:#2D8FF0; 
}
nav ul li a {
    display:block; 
    color:#444; 
}
nav ul li ul {
    position:absolute; 
    width:180px;
    background:#09427C;
    font-size: 12px;    
}
nav ul li ul li {
    width:180px;    
}
nav ul li ul li a {
    display:block; 
    color:#444;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover a {}
nav ul li ul.fallback {
    display:none;
}
nav ul li:hover ul.fallback {
    display:block;
}
</style>


</head>

<body onload="docOnLoad()">
<form id="frmPageHead" name="frmPageHead" action="">

<!-- BANNER START -->
<table id="banner" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="">
    <tr class="">
        <div class="wrap">
            <hgroup>
                <h1 class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" width="163" height="59"></h1>
                    <h2 class="site-heading">Welcome</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- BANNER END -->

<!-- START nav.site-nav -->
<nav class="site-nav">
    <ul class="menu-nav wrap menu menu--hor">
        <li class="menu-nav--home"><a href="javascript:parent.navigate(GetServerPath('NonSHTTP',getSeverDir()))" title="home"><span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>
        <li class="data-sources"><a href="#" title="">Date Sources <span class="icon-caret-down"></span> </a>       
            <li>
                <a href="c_frameset.html?overview.html">Information</a>
                <ul class="fallback">
                <li><a href="c_frameset.html?openaccount.html">New Customer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="c_frameset.html?existingaccount.html">Existing Customer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="c_frameset.html?pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="c_frameset.html?testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="c_frameset.html?servicesoverview.html">Our Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="c_frameset.html?addinfo.html">Additional Info</a>
                <ul class="fallback">
                    <li><a href="c_frameset.html?terms.html">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="c_frameset.html?howto.html">How To's</a></li>                  
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="c_frameset.html?contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                <ul class="fallback">
                        <li><a href="c_frameset.html?cotactdetails.html">Contact Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="c_frameset.html?feedback.html">Your Voice Matters</a></li>
                    <li><a href="c_frameset.html?environement.html">The Environment</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="c_frameset.html?ourproducts.html">Products</a>
                <ul class="fallback">
                <li><a href="c_frameset.html?noise.html">Sound Deadening</a></li>
                    <li><a href="c_frameset.html?wiring.html">Wiring</a></li>                   
            <li><a href="c_frameset.html?connectors.html">Connections</a></li>                  
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Need Help?</a>
                <ul class="fallback">
                    <li><a href="javascript:parent.PageHeader.openHelpWind(helpContext)">Need Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="c_frameset.html?faqs.html">FAQ's</a></li>
                    <li><a href="c_frameset.html?getintouch.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="c_frameset.html?cookies.html">Cookies?</a>
            </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- END menu-nav -->
</nav> <!-- END nav.site-nav -->

</form>
<form id="frmDuy" name="frmDuy" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="ONLINE_HELP" name="ONLINE_HELP" value=""/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've spent quite a lot of time trying to get this to work with little success so any information is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Update:

Now attempting to use layout structure:

```
<head>
   <script> $(function({ $("#header").load("PageHeader.html"); }); </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">

</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="pageNavigation">a
    </div>
    <div id="contentFrames">b
    </div>
    <div id="pageHelp">c
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <h3>footer</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I receive the following error:

SyntaxError: missing : after property id

$(function({ $("#header").load("PageHeader.html"); });

Which points to ("#header"

Update:

Tried this:

```
<body>

<div id="header">
        <script> $(function({ $("#header").load("PageHeader.html"); }); </script>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="pageNavigation">a
    </div>
    <div id="contentFrames">b
    </div>
    <div id="pageHelp">c
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <h3>footer</h3>
</div>
</body>
```

Still receiving the following error:

**SyntaxError: missing : after property id**

$(function({ $("#header").load("PageHeader.html"); });

Which points to ("#header"

Comment: I recommend starting by eliminating the frames. Deal with the menu later. Then you work have to work around the limitations of the frames in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. I would like to remove frames in possibly a years time, but for now i have to look for a work-around.

Comment: put the script aftert the page header is loaded by the dom, else the id won't be find

Comment: try this **$(function(){ 
 $("#header").load("/PageHeader.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
   var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
   alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
 });
}); **
this will help you to debug.
anyway there is a bracket error in your code (and probably also a path error)

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution in jquery: http://viewsboard.com/boards/view/discussion/2/550
Here some example with code: http://deluxe-menu.com/cross-frame-mode-sample.html
Here a simple workaround: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/menu/can-radmenu-expand-over-other-frames-if-it-is-in-a-frame-itself.aspx
here another example: http://www.sothink.com/product/dhtmlmenu/store/crossframe/twomenus/
here another one: http://www.zzzxo.com/q/answers-drop-down-menu-over-frames-14560398.html

This problem seems old, old as frames, can I suggest you to eliminate frames?

**Edit:**
Excluding the tables layout (it was abandoned years ago), you should consider that frame are deprecated in html5.. In your place I should start with some [layout](https://www.google.it/search?q=layout%20html), or also just like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/redesign-main.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<style>
div{
    border-radius:20px; /*for border rounded*/
}
#header{
    height:150px;
    background-color:#FF0;
    min-width:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
#pageNavigation{
    min-height:450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:20%;

    background-color:#666;
    float:left;
    min-width:100px;
    }
#contentFrames{
    min-height:450px;
    width:58%;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#03C;
    float:left;
    }
#pageHelp{
    min-height:450px;
    width:20%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#3F0;
    float:left;
    min-width:100px;
    }
#content{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:90%;
    min-width:720px;
}
#footer{
    height:100px;
    background-color:#FF0;
    min-width:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear:both;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body onload="docOnLoad()">
<div id="header">
    <? //include('pageHeader.html'); ?>
    <h1>header</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="pageNavigation">a
    </div>
    <div id="contentFrames">b
    </div>
    <div id="pageHelp">c
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <h3>footer</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Whilst removing frames is the ideal solution, and something i wanted to do, with the amount of changes that would require would be substantial. As a temporary/time saving measure, i will have to look into the links you've provided.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and example code. The layout you have suggested above, would it be a simple case of replacing my FrameStructure.html page with a <div> and ID structure? How would this impact the current JavaScript code as i can see about 80% of the code uses parent.PageContent... parent.PageHeader.... top.PageHeader.. etc

Comment: @OamPsy It is simple if you are used to play with this kind of things, also an editor can be useful: it let you substitute (search and replaces) all the occurrences of a string. I believe, anyway,  this will takes you not so much time more then re-arrange your menu, don't you think?

Comment: I agree, in theory, the changes are simple. I guess it's the knock-on effects or small issues as a result of the change could be time consuming to fix. But i guess that's where i'll learn the most about problem solving. In terms of text editor, i have been using sublime text for quite some time now which i enjoy. Any others you recommend?

Comment: @OamPsy For the little issues caused by the changes, many attentions before and the browser debugger after, will be enought. Just take your time if you are interested to improving your skills and especially to remain up to date. Gl with it

Comment: @Alessandero - Thanks. Out of interest, how do you include a page using HTML? I can see you've used  <? //include('pageHeader.html'); ?> however this looks like PHP?

Comment: I have tried using: <div id="header">
     <!--#include file="92_PageHeader.html" -->     
     <h1>header</h1>
 </div>

Comment: @OamPsy Yes, sorry I used php because of abituds, if your server doesn't run php you can use the html include(as you did) or the jquery:
**<script> 
    $(function{
      $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
    });
</script>**

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i have attempted to using the approach you have mentioned, however, i am running in to performance issues outlined here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151950/navigation-menu-links    are you able to offer any advice? Thank you.