# Navigation Menu Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I've recently started restructuring a website, which currently uses frames and framesets.

I have now adopted a typical **structure.html**:

```
<body>
<div>
    <div id="headerNavigation"></div>
    <div id="PageContent"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

With the following jQuery scripts to populate the DIVs:

```
<head>
<script>
$.get('PageHeader.html', processHeader, "html").fail(function() { alert("There is a problem loading the header. Please re-try"); });
function processHeader(file_data)
{
    $("#headerNavigation").html(file_data);
}

$.get('TermsConditions.html', processContent, "html").fail(function() { alert("There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try"); });
function processContent(file_data)
{
    $("#PageContent").html(file_data);
}

$.get('Footer.html', processFooter, "html").fail(function() { alert("There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try"); });
function processFooter(file_data)
{
    $("#Footer").html(file_data);
}
</script>
</head>
```

This works great when i specify the Content page, however, i need some kind of jQuery function that forwards/populates the DIV with the correct content when clicking on an item in my Navigation menu - **index.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- jQuery code for drop down nav menus  -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
        $('nav li').hover(
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(300);
            },
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(300);
            }
        );       
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<nav class="site-nav">
<ul class="menu-nav wrap menu menu--hor">
    <li class="data-sources"><a href="#" title="">Date Sources <span class="icon-caret-down"></span> </a>       
        <li>
            <a href="frameset.html?Information.html">Information</a>
            <ul class="fallback">
            <li><a href="frameset.html?ovens.html">Ovens</a></li>
                <li><a href="frameset.html?fridges.html">Fridges</a></li>
                <li><a href="frameset.html?tables.html">Tables</a></li>
                <li><a href="frameset.html?costing.html">Costing</a></li>
                <li><a href="frameset.html?install.html">Installation</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="frameset.html?legal.html">Legal Info</a>
            <ul class="fallback">
                <li><a href="frameset.html?terms.html">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                <li><a href="frameset.html?data.html">Data Protection</a></li>                  
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="frameset.html?contact/html">Contact Us</a>
            <ul class="fallback">
            <li><a href="javascript:openHelpWind('contact')">Contact Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="frameset.html?comments.html">Your Comments</a></li>
                <li><a href="frameset.html?addinfos.html">Additional Info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Need Help?</a>
            <ul class="fallback">
            <li><a href="javascript:parent.PageHeader.openHelpWind(helpContext)">Need Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="externalsite">FAQs</a></li>
                <li><a href="externalsite">Ask our Experts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="frameset.html?cookies.html">Cookies</a>
        </li>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how how i can create a function to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**Update 21-06-2013** Basic Site Skeleton:

**Index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <script src="javascript/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

<title>Welcome</title>
<link id="productStyle" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>

<!-- JavaScript functions to enable dropdown navigation-->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
        $('nav li').hover(
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(300);
            },
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(300);
            }
        );       
    });
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function gofor(a) {
    $.get(a, processContent, 'html').fail(function() { alert('There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try');});
    }

    function processContent(file_data)
    {
        $("#PageContent").html(file_data);
    }

</script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- MENU START -->
<nav class="site-nav">
<ul class="menu-nav ">
    <li class="menu--home"><a href="index.html " title="home"><span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>      
        <li>
        <a href="frameset.html?Information.html">Information</a>
        <ul class="fallback">

            <li><a onclick="gofor('information.html')">Information (go for)</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="gofor('openaccount.html')"> New Customer (Go For)</a>

            <li><a onClick="gofor('information.html')">Information Go For onClick</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:gofor('information.html')">Information Go For HREF</a></li>


            <li><a href="frameset.html?ovens.html">Ovens</a></li>
            <li><a href="frameset.html?fridges.html">Fridges</a></li>
            <li><a href="frameset.html?tables.html">Tables</a></li>
            <li><a href="frameset.html?costing.html">Costing</a></li>
            <li><a href="frameset.html?install.html">Installation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="frameset.html?legal.html">Legal Info</a>
        <ul class="fallback">
                     <li><a href="frameset.html?terms.html">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                 <li><a href="frameset.html?data.html">Data Protection</a></li>                  
                       </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            <ul class="fallback">
      <li><a href="javascript:openHelpWind('contact')">Contact Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="frameset.html?comments.html">Your Comments</a></li>
                <li><a href="frameset.html?addingds.html">Adding Directors Searches</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </li>
</ul> <!-- END menu-nav -->
</nav> <!-- END nav.site-nav -->
<!-- MENU END -->

<section>
<div class="page-heading">
    <h1 class="wrap">Welcome to Tables, Ladders and Chairs </h1>
</div>
<div>

Other welcome content

</div>
</section>
<footer class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
<div class="wrap">
    <small>2013 TL&C’s. </small>
</div>
</footer>
```

**Frameset.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.get('PageHeader.html', processHeader, "html").fail(function() { alert("There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try"); });

function processHeader (file_data)
{
    $("#header").html(file_data);
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="PageContent"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

**PageHeader.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="javascript/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

<title>Page Header</title>

<link id="productStyle" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>

<!-- JavaScript functions to enable dropdown navigation-->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {       
        $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
        $('nav li').hover(
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(300);
            },
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(300);
        }
        );       
    });
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function gofor(a) {
    $.get(a, processContent, 'html').fail(function() { alert('There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try');});
    }

    function processContent(file_data)
    {
        $("#PageContent").html(file_data);
    }

</script>


<!-- MENU START -->
<nav class="site-nav">
<ul class="menu-nav ">
    <li class="menu--home"><a href="index.html " title="home"><span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>      
        <li>
        <a href="frameset.html?Information.html">Information</a>
        <ul class="fallback">

  <li><a onclick="gofor('information.html')">Information (go for)</a></li>
         <li><a onclick="gofor('openaccount.html')"> New Customer (Go For)</a>

            <li><a href="frameset.html?ovens.html">Ovens</a></li>
            <li><a href="frameset.html?fridges.html">Fridges</a></li>
            <li><a href="frameset.html?tables.html">Tables</a></li>
            <li><a href="frameset.html?costing.html">Costing</a></li>
            <li><a href="frameset.html?install.html">Installation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="frameset.html?legal.html">Legal Info</a>
        <ul class="fallback">
                     <li><a href="frameset.html?terms.html">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                 <li><a href="frameset.html?data.html">Data Protection</a></li>                  
                       </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            <ul class="fallback">
      <li><a href="javascript:openHelpWind('contact')">Contact Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="frameset.html?comments.html">Your Comments</a></li>
                <li><a href="frameset.html?addingds.html">Adding Directors Searches</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </li>
</ul> <!-- END menu-nav -->
</nav> <!-- END nav.site-nav -->
<!-- MENU END -->
```

**Information.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Information</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
       <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

</head>

<body>
<form>

    Information about Tables Ladders and Chairs etc.

</form>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, for each link in the menu, add a call to a function like this:

```
<a onclick="$.get('Information.html', processContent, 'html')" >Information</a>
```

As you see, you will reuse the same function used to load the content the first time:

```
$.get('Information.html', processContent, 'html')
```

In this way,you have just called the same 'processContent' but for a different page to load. You can simplify the onclick event more by adding a third function which will be called by the onclick(or href) and then, will call the function to load the content, like this:

```
<a onclick="gofor('Information.html')">Information</a>
```

or this one:

```
<a href="javascript:gofor('Information.html')">Information</a>
```

and then add this simple function:

```
function gofor(page){    
    $.get(page, processContent, 'html').fail(function() { alert('There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try');});
}
```

Obviously you can't use this function to load external content, because it's forbidden by the browsers

Your index page should be something like this, please pay attention to the div with id "pageContent" in it the pages will be loaded and to the function you need to have to load contents in your page.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://modernizr.com/i/js/modernizr.com-custom-2.6.1-01.js"></script>
<title>Welcome</title>
<link id="productStyle" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- JavaScript functions to enable dropdown navigation-->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
        $('nav li').hover(
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(300);
            },
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(300);
            }
        );       
    });
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

function gofor(a) {
$.get(a, processContent, 'html').fail(function() { alert('There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try');});
    }

function processContent(file_data)
    {
        $("#PageContent").html(file_data);
    }

</script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- MENU START -->
<nav class="site-nav">
<ul class="menu-nav ">
    <li class="menu--home"><a href="javascript:gofor('index.html')" title="home"><span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>      
        <li>
        <a href="javascript:gofor('Information.html')">Information</a>
        <ul class="fallback">

  <li><a href="javascript:gofor('information.html')">Information (go for)</a></li>
         <li><a href="gofor('openaccount.html')"> New Customer (Go For)</a>

            <li><a href="javascript:gofor('ovens.html')">Ovens</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:gofor('fridges.html')">Fridges</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:gofor('tables.html')">Tables</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:gofor('costing.html')">Costing</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:gofor('install.html')">Installation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:gofor('legal.html')">Legal Info</a>
        <ul class="fallback">
                     <li><a href="javascript:gofor('terms.html')">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                 <li><a href="javascript:gofor('data.html')">Data Protection</a></li>                  
                       </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            <ul class="fallback">
      <li><a href="javascript:openHelpWind('contact')">Contact Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:gofor('comments.html')">Your Comments</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:gofor('addingds.html')">Adding Directors Searches</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </li>
</ul> <!-- END menu-nav -->
</nav> <!-- END nav.site-nav -->
<!-- MENU END -->

<section>
<div class="page-heading">
    <h1 class="wrap">Welcome to Tables, Ladders and Chairs </h1>
</div>
<div>

Other welcome content

</div>
<div id="PageContent">
</div>
<footer class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="wrap">
        <small>2013 TL&C’s. </small>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: thank you. I am receiving a ReferenceError: gofor is not defined.... In Information.html. I have reuploaded the basic skeleton of my site above.

Comment: @OamPsy 1)You have to add also this function as I explained: function gofor(a){    
    $.get(a, processContent, 'html').fail(function() { alert('There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try');});


}

2)And don't use frameset?page.html but only page.html


3)If you use the onclick event, remove the href attribute from the <a> tag as I showed before

Comment: @OamPsy I can't understand why you modified the pages. in the index page you will have: <html>html tags<head>javascript (menu, load pages) and styles</head><body>here the page structure <div header>(menu)</div><div content>(where you load the pages)</div>what do you want<div footer></div></body></html>

Comment: @OamPsy I added a model of the index page you can use

Comment: Thank you for the Model. I think there may be some confusion. The Index.html page is fine, however, what i am trying to achieve is when a user clicks on Information, they are forwarded to the Information.html page (and the pageHeader.html and footer.html are auto loaded). Not that the Information.html page is loaded within Index.html.

Comment: I have also incorporated your model, including the PageContent <div>. I am presented with the error "There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try" when using <li><a href="javascript:gofor  &   <li><a onClick=":gofor

Comment: I think this was why i was incorporating framset.html in my hyperlink, as it defined the PageHeader, PageContent & Footer.

Comment: It's the problem solved? when you load a page, you have to give the exact path of the file path/page.html. eg if the page is in the same folder of the file which is loading the page, you will use "page.html", if the page to be loaded is in a folder under the file: "folder/page.html"

Comment: Nope, the problem isn't solved. Still receiving "There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try". All my .html files are within the root of the project i.e. "Folder/SiteName/ProjectName" > .html files      Only my .js and .css files are within separate folders.

Comment: Ok, think ive got it working :) Looks like i had mis-spelt the name of a page!

Comment: I understand what you have advised now i.e. - everything is derived from index.html - very neat and smart i have to admit. One question, currently index.html is my landing page and there is a <section> that welcomes the users, tell about the site, products ect... When i click on a link in the Nav Menu, this <section> still appears and the new content is loaded below. As defined in the structure. How do i hide? Should i be hiding? Or instead, remove the contents from <section> and place within a separate .html page? Thanks

Comment: @OamPsy 1) Put <section> in the file that you load when I first time visit the page (so evry time I visit the page or I go to homepage it will be visible)
2) put it simply in the div PageContent, it will be visible only when I visit your site( if I load a page, then i reload the homepage it won't be showed)
3) Add, in the gofor function, something like this code: $('#idOfTheSection').hide();  when the page(the parameter a) is != from homepage (or whatevery is the homepage of your site) else $('#idOfTheSection').show();

Comment: @OamPsy When you'll get more practice you can play with urls (instead of loading page on click), by calling the page like: site/index.html?p=pageName then get the p parameter with js and then load that page in the div (this will let you have a page for each content)

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a play with the hiding/showing content this weekend. Could you explain more about 'playing with URL's? What i am attempting to do is redesign a site that is currently using frames and framesets. If you know of a better approach i would be interested to explore this from the offset. Thanks.

Comment: @OamPsy I mean to create a corrispondence between urls and pages, now the user have to go in your home and then click for a content to reach a particular page, you can, using url parameters( something like www.yoursite.com?page=pagename ),to load a particular content. You just need to elaborate the url. eg:code to get the url, split the part needed and show it with alert:
var uu = document.URL;
var uuu = uu.split("?page=");
alert(uuu[1]);
all the menu links (urls) will be like: "www.mysite.it/index.html?page=name "then, when you already know the page, you can call gofor(uuu[1]) to load content

Comment: Thank you for the advice, that makes a lot of sense. I have now started to restructure my site, taking advantage of some of jQuery's features, one of which - the accordion. I have run into a problem with browser testing outlined here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314831/jquery-accordion-functioning-in-ie-not-ff

Comment: @OamPsy Try to don't repeat the same script loading in different pages, expecially if 1 page will contain another one. When you load a page into another the two contents will coexist, so it's better to avoid the redundant code:include the script once and where it's needed ( I'm not sure, but I think you can include all the script files into index)

Comment: Thanks! I have doubled checked my code and the warning i mentioned previously is from another .JS file. I have removed that now. I have also removed implementing the same scripts from both pages, and only referencing in the Index.html page... No errors in FireBug. Functions and displays as expected in IE, however still fully expanded in FF.

Comment: @OamPsy fully expanded? Mmh, the menu is fully expanded? How it should looks like? and how it looks like?

Comment: @OamPsy     $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
        $('nav li').hover(
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(300);
            },
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(300);
            }
        );       
    }); this is the function which let the menu works, It seems to work for me, I don't know if there is some conflicts or you removed something, but, this function and the jquery library are enough for the menu

Comment: I think there is some confusion, my menu works as expected. It is the accordion which i am importing from Products.html that is fully expanded.

Comment: This is now working (the accordion).. For some reason, when i remove other .JS scripts from Products.html and add them to Index.html the accordion is imported and functions/displays as expected - very odd.

Comment: I am experiencing a issue with the Back button on any browser, with this form of navigation i imagine. I have outlined my question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011817/website-structure-has-lost-browser-back-capability   As you kindly help me create my nav, i would appreciate it if you could take a look. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for you to load all those elements via javascript. In fact I would argue that it's bad practice. You're making unnecessary calls that will lead to longer loading times for your visitors. The standard practice is to load your initial content and then use javascript as needed to respond to user commands.

I understand what you're trying to do with splitting up the content into separate partials (Header, footer, etc..) but this isn't usually how it's done. There are some template engines that would do exactly what you're trying to achieve without requiring extra ajax calls to pull in regular html content. Here are some basic examples of separating out reusable content:

[PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (Server side):

```
<?php include 'pageheader.html'; ?>
<div>My main content</div>
<?php include 'footer.html'; ?>
```

[Handlebars.js](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers) (Client side)

```
{{>pageheader}}
<div>My main content</div>
{{>footer}}
```

Having said that, if you absolutely must stick with the current set up, then you would just need to parse out the url from the a tag and send that to your processContent function. Here is an example of how you can do that using jquery:

```
$('li').on('click', function (e) {
    var url = $(this).find(">:first-child").attr('href');
    $.get(url, processContent, "html").fail(function() { alert("There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try"); });
});
```

The above code basically just binds to the click event of every li and grabs the a tag's href value before passing that value to your processContent function

Comment: thanks for the input, sorry, could you explain without PHP as i am merely using HTML, JS and jQuery. Thanks

Comment: I included php in there as one example of a server side engine that has a way to render partial html files on page load. You can use any technology that allows this functionality, some others include python, asp.net mvc, ruby on rails, etc.. The point that I was trying to make is that generally you don't want to make several javascript calls to load recurring content because of the extra network calls that are required to get that content. There are languages and frameworks out there that are much more suited for that task.

Comment: You are right, using $('li) click event has significant increased my page loading times. What other routes could you advise of?

Comment: Generally, you want to serve up most of your core content in one swoop. That's where using a templating engine comes in. If you can only use HTML and JS consider using Handlebars.js but make sure to precompile your templates. If you are very uncomfortable learning Handlebars then consider loading the entire html page in one document without using javascript and hide the content that you want to be hidden using css. Then use javascript to show/hide content on li clicks as opposed to loading it from the server.

Comment: If you see that it's too much content to load in one swoop then still use javascript to load in the content from separate files but add a visual indicator (spinner for example) that something is loading, it works wonders for user experience.