# jQuery Accordion – Functioning In IE, Not FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, cross-browser

I have created a simple accordion in my **products.html** page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb">
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/redesign_js.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/redesign-main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-heading">
    <h1 class="wrap">Products</h1>
</div>

<div class="ctr-full">
    <form class="wrap createsrc" method="post">
        <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Product 1</h3>
            <div>
                <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi.</p>
            </div>
        <h3>Product 2</h3>
            <div>
                <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo.</p>
            </div>
        <h3>Product 3</h3>
            <div>
                <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. </p>
            </div>
        <h3>Product 4</h3>
            <div>
                <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This appears and functions in IE, FF and Chrome.
However, when is page is imported/loaded into my index.html page (into a DIV), the accordion functions/displays as expected in IE, but is always expanded in FF.

**Index.html page:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <script src="javascript/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/redesign-main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/redesign_js.js"></script>

<!-- New JavaScript functions to enable dropdown navigation. -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
        $('nav li').hover(
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(300);
            },
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(300);
            }
        );       
    });
</script>

  <!-- New JavaScript functions to load page from Nav menu into #PageContent DIV -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function getPageContent(a) {
        $.get(a, processContent, 'html').fail(function() { alert('There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try');});
    }

    function processContent(file_data)
    {
        $("#PageContent").html(file_data);
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- MENU START -->
<nav class="site-nav">
<ul class="menu-nav">
    <li class="data-sources"><a href="#" title="">Date Sources <span class="icon-caret-down"></span> </a>       
    <li>
       <a onClick="getPageContent(‘products.html')">Products</a>
       <ul class="fallback">                    
         <li><a onClick="getPageContent('products.html')"> Products  Overview</a></li>                  
         <li><a onClick="getPageContent('existingaccount.html')">Existing Customer</a></li>
         <li><a onClick="getPageContent('pricing.html')">Pricing</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>   
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<!-- MENU END -->
</div>
    <div id="PageContent">
</div>

<footer class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
<div class="wrap">
    <small class="fr">&copy</small>
</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

When debugging in FF, I have noticed a receive an error in the Error Console pointing to jquery-1.9.1.min.js

‘function Validation.prototype.setMask(name, value, blur){  //general method for’ line 105

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try with an unminified version of jQuery for debugging. The line number you currently got is not representative. Btw, [jQuery 1.9.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js) does not contain *that* code. Are you sure it says that?

Comment: @Bergi - I have doubled checked my code and the warning i mentioned is from another .JS file. I have removed that now. I have also removed implementing the same scripts from both pages, and only referencing in the Index.html page... No errors in FireBug. Functions and displays as expected in IE, however still fully expanded in FF.

Comment: This is now working (the accordion).. For some reason, when i remove other .JS scripts from Products.html and add them to Index.html the accordion is imported and functions/displays as expected - very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't understand you right, but I think the issue is happening because you are implementing the same scripts in both pages, try to remove the scripts from the products.html file.