# Website Structure Has Lost Browser Back Capability

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've recently started to redesign/revamp a website that used frames/framesets (i believe is was created back in the 1990's!)

I have opted for a basic structure outlined below:

```
<body>
  header & navigation
  content
  footer
</bod>
```

Where the above is defined in my Index.html page, the header/navigation and footer are static.. The content changes depending on what item is selected from the navigation menu.

The only problem i have now is that, for example, a user comes on the homepage (index.html), then selects and item from the nav menu, which refreshes the ... If a user clicks the Back button on any browser, they do not go back to the homepage, but to the previous browsers location, say, they came from Google search, they would be redirected there.

**Index.html:**

```
    <html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<script src="javascript/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/redesign_js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/carousel_js.js"></script>

<!-- New JavaScript functions to enable dropdown navigation -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
        $('nav li').hover(
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(300);
            },
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(300);
            }
        );       
    });
</script>

<!-- New JavaScript functions to enable refresh of page content DIV -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function getPageContent(a) {
        $.get(a, processContent, 'html').fail(function() { alert('There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try');});
        $('#welcome').hide();
    }

    function processContent(file_data)
    {
        $("#PageContent").html(file_data);
    }
</script>



<style> 

/*nav {background:#FFF;float:left;}*/
nav ul {
    text-align:left;    
}
nav ul li {
    float:left; 
    display:inline;
    border-right: 1px solid #083D72;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background:#2D8FF0; 
}
nav ul li a {
    display:block; 
    color:#444; 
}
nav ul li ul {
    position:absolute; 
    width:180px;
    background:#09427C;
    font-size: 12px;    
}
nav ul li ul li {
    width:180px;    
}
nav ul li ul li a {
    display:block; 
    color:#444;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover a {}
nav ul li ul.fallback {
    display:none;
}
nav ul li:hover ul.fallback {
    display:block;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr class="">
    <div class="wrap">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" width="163" height="59" alt="Tables and Chairs"></h1>
            <h2 class="heading">Welcome to Tables and Chairs</h2>
        </hgroup>
    </div>
</tr>
</table>

<!-- MENU START -->
<nav class="site-nav">
<ul class="menu-nav wrap menu menu--hor">
<li class="data-sources"><a href="#" title="">Date <span class="icon-caret-down"></span> </a>       
    <li>
        <a onClick="getPageContent('Information.html')">Information</a>
        <ul class="fallback">
        <li><a onClick="getPageContent('ovens.html')">Ovens</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="getPageContent('fridges.html')">Fridges</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="getPageContent('tables.html')">Tables</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="getPageContent('costing.html')">Costing</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="getPageContent('install.html')">Installation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a onClick="getPageContent('legal.html')">Legal Info</a>
        <ul class="fallback">
            <li><a onClick="getPageContent('terms.html')">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="getPageContent('data.html')">Data Protection</a></li>                  
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a onClick="getPageContent('contact.html')">Contact Us</a>
        <ul class="fallback">
        <li><a href="javascript:openHelpWind('contact')">Contact Details</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="getPageContent('comments.html')">Your Comments</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="getPageContent('addinfos.html')">Additional Info</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a onClick="getPageContent('cookies.html')">Cookies</a>
    </li>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<!-- MENU END -->


<div id="PageContent">
    <section id="welcome">
        <div class="page-heading">
            <h1 class="wrap">Welcome to Tables and Chairs</h1>
        </div>


        <div class="ctr-full">
            <form class="wrap createsrc" method="post">
            <div class="grid one-whole">
                <section class="box">
                    <fieldset>
                    <ul id="carousel">
                                <li><img width="200" height="133" src="images/slideImage1.png" /></li>
                                <li><img width="200" height="133" src="images/slideImage2.png" /></li>
                                <li><img width="200" height="133" src="images/slideImage3.png" /></li>
                                <li><img width="200" height="133" src="images/slideImage4.png" /></li>
                            </ul>
                </fieldset>
                </section>
            </div>
            <br>                    
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<footer class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
<div class="wrap">
    <small class="fr">&copy; 2013 T&C All rights reserved</small>
</div>
</footer> <!-- END footer.site-footer -->

</body>
</html>
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Update **

Thanks for the feedback guys. I'm attempting to implement Ben Almans plugin.

I have downloaded his full plugin, and placed the following code in my head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">


<script src="javascript/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>


<link type="text/css" href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/redesign_js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.ba-hashchange.js"></script>

<!-- New JavaScript functions to enable dropdown navigation -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
        $('nav li').hover(
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(300);
            },
            function () {
                $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(300);
            }
        );       
    });
</script>

<!-- New JavaScript functions to enable history navigation -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){

      // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the hash changes, gets the
      // hash and adds the class "selected" to any matching nav link.
      $(window).hashchange( function(){
        var hash = location.hash;

        // Set the page title based on the hash.
        document.title = 'The hash is ' + ( hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) || 'blank' ) + '.';

        // Iterate over all nav links, setting the "selected" class as-appropriate.
        $('#nav li').each(function(){
          var that = $(this);
          that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'selected' );
        });
      })

      // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
      // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
      $(window).hashchange();

    });
</script>



<!-- New JavaScript functions to enable refresh of page content DIV -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function getPageContent(a) {
        $.get(a, processContent, 'html').fail(function() { alert('There is a problem loading a resource. Please re-try');});
        $('#welcome').hide();
    }

    function processContent(file_data)
    {
        $("#PageContent").html(file_data);
    }
</script>



<style> 

/*as per earlier post....*/

</style>

</head>

<body>
```

The #tag doesnt appear to work as in Firbug i am seeing an error of:

TypeError: $.browser is undefined.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Without looking I would guess you need a jquery history plugin

Comment: That is expected behavior. You are not navigating to other pages, you are loading them using ajax. So in effect your home page is never browsed out. Hence, back will take you to from where you came from.

Comment: you could use hash for that

Comment: Or the HTML5 history API

Comment: On an unrelated note, things like the X-UA-Compatible meta will have little effect if you keep the page in quirks mode. Put a proper DOCTYPE on top. Oh, and take that `div` out of that `tr`, it looks terrible.

Comment: @MrLister - Thanks for the tips, with regards to DOCTYPE, are you refering to: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang='en'>

Comment: @OamPsy Since the page is in HTML5, you should use the HTML5 version, `<!DOCTYPE html>` otherwise it won't validate. And a `lang` attribute in the `html` start tag is OK, but not mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

Because they're not actually going anywhere - your links appear to simply alter the content dynamically, in place, which means they never technically leave the index page and the back button is functioning correctly.

Plenty of technologies offer templating techniques, there really is no need for such a primitive hack to use a "master" page; define each of the pages distinctly and use links to string them together into a browsable site.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As im redesigning the whole site, i would prefer to do it the 'proper way'. Could you help with "define each of the pages distinctly and use links to string them together into a browsable site." Thanks

Comment: Essentially, replace code like `<a onClick="getPageContent('fridges.html')">` with code like `<a href="fridges.html">`

Comment: @Quentin - Thanks Quentin, whilst that would take me to the fridges page and have the Back capability, it would not automatically import the dropdown header/nav and footer.

Comment: @OamPsy —  Do that with a template system (either server side or at build time).

Answer (score 2):

Your simplest solution would be to add a hash to the end of the url. As you're already using jQuery, you should probably just use a plugin: e.g. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin

Look at the [demo page](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/)

Expanding on some of the comments:

It is more normal (traditionally) to have multiple html files on a web server and clicking a link on the navigation will take you to that file e.g. your website folder could have 3 files in it:

- index.html
- about.html
- contact.html

Then your users would click links on your page with `<a href="index.html">Home</a>` (as an example) which would cause the web server to serve the index page to the requesting user agent.

Generally people have elements that are the same across multiple pages, for example headers and footers. In order to achieve this without copy pasting into all of your files you'll need a server side preprocessor e.g. PHP or ASP.Net which have the concept of Master pages and includes respectively.

Of course, there is also the option of using an MVC type framework - but I don't want to throw that into the mix as well.

Comment: I don't think that using jQuery is a blanket for not doing proper linkage as a user would expect; yes, one-page websites have become a bit of a thing, but this doesn't look like that's what it's intended to be _per se_. The OP is moving away from frames but not really making any improvement in that sense.

Comment: @RobH - Thank you for the link, i now understand why it is behaving like this. Ive taken a look at the link you provided, seems simple enough.

Comment: @Grant Thomas - Thanks for your comments. As im redesigning the whole site, if you could shed some light - with examples, of how to 'really' improve away from frames i would appreciate it.

Comment: @GrantThomas - Adding hashes would make each page have its own link. I do, of course, agree that it would be better to have several pages with proper links.

Comment: @RobH - Hi RobH, could you give me more details about "having several pages with proper links".. As you can probably understand, if im redesigning a site, i would prefer to do it the right way. Thanks

Comment: @RobH - Thanks for taking them time to explain that. With regards to server side processor, the site is using HTML5, jQuery and hopefully host on IIS.

Comment: @OamPsy - if you're hosting on IIS, you can use ASP.Net and a master page. http://www.asp.net/vwd

Comment: @RobH ideally i would prefer to avoid asp/masterpages.aspx's for this project and stick with HTML.

Comment: @OamPsy - fair enough, just add the hashes then.